# CNF with python, how to remove tautologies

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I have an AI exercise to do. The goal is to print on screen a CNF(n,m,k). It is a boolean formule with n letter, m clauses and each clause must have k letters. I have this rule that capital letters are true and small letters are false. Furthermore I have to remove redundancies and tautologies from the clauses. Eg CNF(6,3,3) could be something like this:

```
[[A,true]or[b,false]or[D,true]] and
[[B,true]or[d,false]or[a,false]] and 
[[d,false]or[A,true]or[B,true]]
```

you can see here we have 3 clauses exactly with 3 letters and the alphabet is 6 letters (6 capital and 6 small). Here we have no redundacies or tautologies. A redundancy is something like [[A,true]or[A,true]]. A tautology is something like [[A,true]or[A,false]].
Now I post my python code, it works but I remove only the redundancies. So, as I've written in the question, I need to remove tautologies.
Here's the code

```
import random
import string
import sys
import os

#This function create the list of tuple
# n = number of symbols, m = nuber of clauses, k = clause length
def createTuple(n):
    if n > 26:
        print("it's impossible to have more than 25 letters")
        sys.exit()
    # creo lista di 25 numeri e la mescolo
    my_list = [0] * (2 * n)
    for x in range(0, 2 * n):
        my_list[x] = x
    random.shuffle(my_list)

    # creo la lista di simboli minuscoli o maiuscoli
    symbols = [0] * (2 * n)
    x = 0
    for count in range(0, n):
        symbols[count] = string.ascii_lowercase[count]
    for count in range(n, 2 * n):
        symbols[count] = string.ascii_uppercase[count - n]
    symbols_rand = [0] * (2 * n)
    for count in range(0, 2 * n):
        symbols_rand[count] = symbols[my_list[count]]
    list_tuple = [0] * (2 * n)
    for counts in range(0, (2 * n)):
        if symbols_rand[counts].islower():
            list_tuple[counts] = [(symbols_rand[counts]), False]
        if symbols_rand[counts].isupper():
            list_tuple[counts] = [(symbols_rand[counts]), True]
    return list_tuple


#This function create the CNF
def createCnf(n, m, k):
    list_tuple = createTuple(n)
    stot = ""
    ki = ""
    x = 0
    i = 0
    countx = 0
    for count in range(0, m):
        ktot = "{"
        temple_tuple = createTuple(n)
        temple_tuple2 = []
        for index in range(0, k):
            #REDUNDANCY CONTROL
            i = index
            while(temple_tuple[i] == None):
               i += 1
            countx = 0
            #TAUTOLOGY CONTROL (WORKING ONLY WHEN THE TWO ELEMENTS ARE CLOSE)
            while countx < len(temple_tuple2):
                x = temple_tuple[i][0]
                if temple_tuple2[countx][0].isupper():
                    c = temple_tuple2[countx][0].lower()
                else:
                    c = temple_tuple2[countx][0].upper()

                if (x == c):
                    i += 1
                    print("tautologia trovata")
                    countx = 0
                else:
                    countx = countx + 1
            ki = temple_tuple[i]
            temple_tuple2.append(ki)
            temple_tuple[i] = None
            if index != (k - 1):
                ktot += str(ki) + " or "
            elif index == (k - 1):
                ktot += str(ki)
            # HERE TAUTOLOGIES END
        ktot += "}"
        if count != (m - 1):
            stot += ktot + " and "
        elif count == (m - 1):
            stot += ktot
    print(stot)


lista_tuple = createTuple(6)
createCnf(6,3,3)
```

Comment: There's no question in here, though it does sound like you want us to write your code for you. Try your hand at eliminating tautologies. Once you're stuck, post a [mcve].

Comment: My question is if you have an idea on how to remove tautology. And between the two #comments (TAUTOLOGY CONTROL-HERE TAUTOLOGIES END) there is my code where I try to remove them. So in that part of the code I'm stuck.

Comment: In the future, if you answer your own question, put it as an answer rather than editing your question. People who have similar concerns can then see both the issue and the resolution.

Comment: Are you happy now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer

```
import random
import string
import sys
import os

 #This function create the list of tuple
 # n = number of symbols, m = nuber of clauses, k = clause length
def createTuple(n):
if n > 26:
    print("it's impossible to have more than 25 letters")
    sys.exit()
# creo lista di 25 numeri e la mescolo
my_list = [0] * (2 * n)
for x in range(0, 2 * n):
    my_list[x] = x
random.shuffle(my_list)

# creo la lista di simboli minuscoli o maiuscoli
symbols = [0] * (2 * n)
x = 0
for count in range(0, n):
    symbols[count] = string.ascii_lowercase[count]
for count in range(n, 2 * n):
    symbols[count] = string.ascii_uppercase[count - n]
symbols_rand = [0] * (2 * n)
for count in range(0, 2 * n):
    symbols_rand[count] = symbols[my_list[count]]
list_tuple = [0] * (2 * n)
for counts in range(0, (2 * n)):
    if symbols_rand[counts].islower():
        list_tuple[counts] = [(symbols_rand[counts]), False]
    if symbols_rand[counts].isupper():
        list_tuple[counts] = [(symbols_rand[counts]), True]
return list_tuple


#This function create the CNF
def createCnf(n, m, k):
list_tuple = createTuple(n)
stot = ""
ki = ""
x = 0
i = 0
countx = 0
for count in range(0, m):
    ktot = "{"
    temple_tuple = createTuple(n)
    temple_tuple2 = []
    for index in range(0, k):
        #REDUNDANCY CONTROL
        i = index
        while(temple_tuple[i] == None):
           i += 1
        countx = 0
        #TAUTOLOGY CONTROL (WORKING ONLY WHEN THE TWO ELEMENTS ARE CLOSE)
        while countx < len(temple_tuple2):
            x = temple_tuple[i][0]
            if temple_tuple2[countx][0].isupper():
                c = temple_tuple2[countx][0].lower()
            else:
                c = temple_tuple2[countx][0].upper()

            if (x == c):
                i += 1
                print("tautologia trovata")
                countx = 0
            else:
                countx = countx + 1
        ki = temple_tuple[i]
        temple_tuple2.append(ki)
        temple_tuple[i] = None
        if index != (k - 1):
            ktot += str(ki) + " or "
        elif index == (k - 1):
            ktot += str(ki)
        # HERE TAUTOLOGIES END
    ktot += "}"
    if count != (m - 1):
        stot += ktot + " and "
    elif count == (m - 1):
        stot += ktot
print(stot)


lista_tuple = createTuple(6)
createCnf(6,3,3)
```